# VB.Net WebRequest and CloudFlare

Tags: vb.net, webrequest, cloudflare

Obviously CloudFlare messes with the response of a WebRequest but I've caught this result and opened a webbrowser instead which loads through to the site and (I presume) gives me a cookie.

Later I might want to call back and rather than repeat the browser process I'm trying a webrequest using the cookie from the browser.

I'm winging it here but on the browser (once the site has loaded normally) I have:

```
WebRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", WebBrowser.Document.Cookie)
SmarkWeb.UseCookies = True
```

But the next webrequest still fails at cloudflare while the cookied browser can navigate around the site fine.

Any hints on what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have control over the website, specifically the Cloudflare DNS? If you do, generate a random string of 16 chars (sufficiently random so nobody else can easily guess it) and set CNAME to point to the website's IP & have it bypass Cloudflare. Use this CNAME specifically for your program.